# ValueError: Unable to find token seed! Did https://translate.google.com change?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtts

I am making an assistant that uses gTTS and Google Speech but this error appears. It is fine with speech recognition as it can recognize without faults. I tested with print function however when I want text-to-speech, this bug comes.
...

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from time import ctime
import time
import playsound
import os
import random
from gtts import gTTS
import webbrowser

r = sr.Recognizer()


def record_audio(ask=False):
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        if ask:
            watson_speak(ask)
        audio = r.listen(source)
        voice_data = ''
        try:
            voice_data = r.recognize_google(audio)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            watson_speak("Sorry, I did not catch that")
        except sr.RequestError:
            watson_speak("I am offline right now")
        return voice_data


def watson_speak(audio_string):
    tts = gTTS(text=audio_string, lang='en')
    r = random.randint(1, 10000000)
    audio_file = 'audio-' + str(r) + '.mp3'
    tts.save(audio_file)
    playsound.playsound(audio_file)
    print(audio_string)
    os.remove(audio_file)


def respond(voice_data):
    if 'what is your name' in voice_data:
        watson_speak("My name is Watson")
    if 'what time is it' in voice_data:
        watson_speak(ctime())
    if 'search' in voice_data:
        search = record_audio("What do you want to search for?")
        url = "https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=" + search
        webbrowser.get().open(url)
        watson_speak("Here is what I found for " + search)
    if 'find location' in voice_data:
        location = record_audio("What is the location?")
        url = "https://google.nl/maps/place/" + location + "/&amp;"
        webbrowser.get().open(url)
        watson_speak("Here is the location of " + location)
    if 'exit' in voice_data:
        exit()


time.sleep(1)
watson_speak("How can I help you?")
while 1:
    voice_data = record_audio()
    respond(voice_data)
```

...
Not sure what I did wrong. Some guidance would be greatly appreciated. It keeps asking for a token seed which I am not sure about.

Answer (score 2):

Do both these upgrades

```
pip3 install gTTS-token --upgrade
pip3 install gTTS --upgrade
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You should consider checking your gTTS-token package version. If you installed the package via pip try this line in a command prompt:

```
pip install gTTS-token --upgrade
```

This was at least in my case the fix for this kind of error message

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Google has updated and switched to another way of generating speech.

This issue is currently open on GitHub, you can check for updates [here](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/issues/232).

It will probably take a while for this to get fixed as the devs need to understand what changes were done by Google.

Comment: The ISSUE has been resolved and it seems updating go **gtts version 2.1.2** and newest resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to reinstall gTTS

```
sudo pip uninstall gTTS
sudo pip install gTTS
```

Try updating gTTS as well as **requests**. This helps.
If still you get error and you have both anaconda as well as python in your local, try to debug `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`, if upgrading gTTS is reflecting your package and you are using the same.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error sometimes but sometimes the code run perfectly, may be it is problem with gtts or pyaudio. I recommend you to use pyttsx library which is i think much better than gtts as i working on it and gives me the best results.

you can check the installation of pyttsx [here](https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to update gTTs-token package
For that use below command :

```
pip install gTTS-token --upgrade
```

this will update the current package

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and reinstalling of gTTS worked for me.